# Promote dependencies from virtual artifactory to test/staging local artifactory using Jfrog-cli

Tags: go, devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am using a virtual repo, testing local repo and staging local repo.

Using jfrog  CLI i am able to build the go code as

```
jf go build
```

All the dependencies are being pulled to virtual artifactory.

**I need to promote these dependencies to test and staging artifactory. How can i do this in jfrog?  Whats the expected process for this now?**

**More details:-**
I have configured jfrog cli and configuration is as below :-

```
jf config show

Server ID:                      demo-go-repo-local
JFrog platform URL:             http://172.30.149.181:8081/
Artifactory URL:                http://172.30.149.181:8081/artifactory/
Distribution URL:               http://172.30.149.181:8081/distribution/
Xray URL:                       http://172.30.149.181:8081/xray/
Mission Control URL:            http://172.30.149.181:8081/mc/
Pipelines URL:                  http://172.30.149.181:8081/pipelines/
User:                           admin
Password:                       ***
Default:                        true
```

**cat /root/dir/artifactory-go-example/.jfrog/projects/go.yaml**

```
version: 1
type: go
resolver:
  repo: demo-go-repo-virtual
  serverId: demo
deployer:
  repo: demo-go-repo-local
  serverId: demo
```

**jf rt go build **

```
11:35:42 [Warn] You are using a deprecated syntax of the command.
        The new command syntax is quite similar to the syntax used by the native go client.
        All you need to do is to add 'jf' as a prefix to the command.
        For example:
        $ jf go ...
        The --build-name and --build-number options are still supported.
11:35:42 [Info] Using go: go version go1.19.2 linux/amd64

go: downloading rsc.io/quote v1.5.2
go: downloading rsc.io/sampler v1.3.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add --build-name and --build-number:

   `jf rt go build —-build-name mybuild —-buildnumber 1`
2. publish your buildinfos with:

   `jf rt bp mybuild 1`
3. promote the build:

   `jf rt bpr mybuild 1 <target_repo>`

see here for more details: [jfrog-cli-ref](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory)